# How to copy multiple files in one layer using a Dockerfile?

Tags: dockerfile

The following `Dockerfile` contains four `COPY` layers:

```
COPY README.md ./
COPY package.json ./
COPY gulpfile.js ./
COPY __BUILD_NUMBER ./
```

How to copy these files using one layer instead? The following was tried:

```
COPY [
    "__BUILD_NUMBER ./",
    "README.md ./",
    "gulpfile ./",
    "another_file ./",
]
```

Answer (score 854, accepted):

```
COPY README.md package.json gulpfile.js __BUILD_NUMBER ./
```

or

```
COPY ["__BUILD_NUMBER", "README.md", "gulpfile", "another_file", "./"]
```

You can also use wildcard characters in the sourcefile specification. [See the docs for a little more detail](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/copy).

**Directories are special!** If you write

```
COPY dir1 dir2 ./
```

that actually works like

```
COPY dir1/* dir2/* ./
```

If you want to copy multiple directories (not their contents) under a destination directory in a single command, you'll need to set up the build context so that your source directories are under a common parent and then `COPY` that parent.

Comment: Note that if the sources are directories, this copies the directory *contents*, not the directories themselves.

Comment: Note also that the destination directory is the same.  If you do alot of different files with different destinations, then you may want to consider constructing an overlay filesystem (like a chroot), then turning that into a `tar` archive, and adding it with ADD.

Comment: @Claudiu How to copy the folders themselves?

Comment: @k0pernikus you can say COPY myDir1 ./MyDir1/

Comment: @manuel-manhart  Is there anyone who knows if we can parameterize the list of files using a Build Parameter? https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/38532?

Comment: @tudor I don't understand how to do what you proposed within a dockerfile.  Would you consider writing an answer to detail your technique so that I can try it?

Comment: @Wyck see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add under the paragraph "If <src> is a local tar archive in a recognized compression format"

Answer (score 155):

```
COPY <all> <the> <things> <last-arg-is-destination>/
```

Note: the trailing `/` is required when copying from multiple sources.

But here is an important excerpt from the docs:

> If you have multiple Dockerfile steps that use different files from
> your context, COPY them individually, rather than all at once. This
> ensures that each step’s build cache is only invalidated (forcing the
> step to be re-run) if the specifically required files change.

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy

Comment: do you know if we can parameterize "all the things"??? Using build parameters? https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/38532???

Comment: @MarcellodeSales not sure why you would need that. Why dont you create a base image without these files and then the child images have the copy instruction in them - if they need to define the path anyways it does not make much of a difference. Or you could just leave it out ot the image(s) completely and mount it into the container - there you have the .env files to have this configurable.

Comment: Also you can always copy over an existing path anyways, since the file system is layered, it will overlap / shadow the pre existing content.

Comment: @ManuelManhart, I'm building a Dynamic Parameterized Image with ONBUILD COPY... As part of a Platform, I'm hiding the complexity of what needs to be done in the image, so, that's why I need the values to be provided as a parameter.

Comment: @MarcellodeSales I dont think that this is supported right now / yet. But you could use build arguments to have it encapsulated, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43654656/dockerfile-if-else-condition-with-external-arguments

Answer (score 28):

It might be worth mentioning that you can also create a `.dockerignore` file, to exclude the files and directories that you **don't** want to copy:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file

> Before the docker CLI sends the context to the docker daemon, it looks for a file named .dockerignore in the root directory of the context. If this file exists, the CLI modifies the context to exclude files and directories that match patterns in it. This helps to avoid unnecessarily sending large or sensitive files and directories to the daemon and potentially adding them to images using ADD or COPY.

Answer (score 27):

The original answer warns about an exception handling directories. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30316600/3257491

If you want to achieve this with directories where you just want to include one or more directories and zero or more specific files you can use `.dockerignore`:

`.dockerignore` file to ignore everything except `src` directory, `test` directory `package.json` file and `package-lock.json` file:

```
*
!src
!test
!package.json
!package-lock.json
```

Then `Dockerfile`:

```
COPY . ./
```

This will include just the files included in exceptions in the `.dockerignore` file.

Answer (score 19):

simple

```
COPY README.md  package.json gulpfile.js __BUILD_NUMBER ./
```

from the [doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)

> If multiple  resources are specified, either directly or due to
>   the use of a wildcard, then  must be a directory, and it must
>   end with a slash /.

Answer (score 13):

To make it review friendly, you may need a multiline `COPY` command. E.g. if the list of files to copy is very long.

Backslash escaping end of lines treats this like this:

```
COPY __BUILD_NUMBER    \
     README.md         \
     gulpfile          \
     another_file      \
     ./
```

I could find an [example with backslash](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-17-breaking-up-long-lines-in-your-dockerfile) for `RUN` command, but not for `COPY`. It works though for `COPY` as well.