# How to run copy command via docker RUN

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need to reduce my Docker image size so I need to run all copy files command to single shell command 
This is my Docker file copy command

```
COPY rdkafka.ini /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/
COPY 20-rdkafka.ini /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/
COPY apache2.conf /etc/apache2/
COPY php.ini /etc/php/7.0/apache2/
```

Into single command

```
RUN cp rdkafka.ini /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/ && cp 20-rdkafka.ini /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/ && apache2.conf /etc/apache2/ && php.ini /etc/php/7.0/apache2/
```

I am getting this error

```
cp: cannot stat 'rdkafka.ini': No such file or directory
```

Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because `RUN cp ...` is not the same as `COPY`. `COPY` copies files from your *host* machine to the image, `RUN` runs *inside* the container during it's build process, and fails because there really is "No such file or directory" in there.

And looking at the [COPY documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30256386/how-to-copy-multiple-files-in-one-layer-using-a-dockerfile), there really is not a way to copy multiple files to multiple destinations with one `COPY`, only multiple sources to one destination.

What you probably can do, if you really want, is to `COPY` everything first to one directory, for example `/tmp`, and then use the `RUN cp /tmp/rdkafka.ini /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/ && ...`.

Comment: Thanks Teemu. I will try your suggestion

Comment: @teemu-risikko tried the same but no luck. I'm getting error cp: cannot stat No such file or directory. I first copied all the files and then running cp in RUN.