# Docker build command fails on COPY

Tags: docker

Hi I have a docker file which is failing on the **COPY** command. It was running fine initially but then it suddenly crashed during the build process. The Docker file basically sets up the dev environment and authenticate with GCP.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

## ENV Variables
ENV PYTHON_VERSION="3.6.5"
ENV BUCKET_NAME='detection-sandbox'
ENV DIRECTORY='/usr/local/gcloud'

# Update and Install packages
RUN apt-get update -y \
 && apt-get install -y \
 curl \
 wget \
 tar \
 xz-utils \
 bc \
 build-essential \
 cmake \
 curl \
 zlib1g-dev \
 libssl-dev \
 libsqlite3-dev \
 python3-pip \
 python3-setuptools \
 unzip \
 g++ \
 git \
 python-tk

 # Install Python 3.6.5
RUN wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VERSION}/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tar.xz \
    && tar -xvf Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tar.xz \
    && rm -rf Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tar.xz \
    && cd Python-${PYTHON_VERSION} \
    && ./configure \
    && make install \
    && cd / \
    && rm -rf Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}

# Install pip
RUN curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py \
    && python3 get-pip.py \
    && rm get-pip.py

# Add SNI support to Python
RUN pip --no-cache-dir install \
        pyopenssl \
        ndg-httpsclient \
        pyasn1

## Download and Install Google Cloud SDK
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/gcloud \
    && curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com > install.sh \
    && bash install.sh --disable-prompts --install-dir=${DIRECTORY}

# Adding the package path to directory
ENV PATH $PATH:${DIRECTORY}/google-cloud-sdk/bin

# working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./ \
     testproject-264512-9de8b1b35153.json ./
```

It fails at this step :

```
Step 13/21 : COPY requirements.txt ./      testproject-264512-9de8b1b35153.json ./
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder942576416/testproject-264512-9de8b1b35153.json: no such file or directory
```

Any leads in this would be helpful.

Comment: `COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder942576416/testproject-264512-9de8b1b35153.json: no such file or directory` means that the file testproject-264512-9de8b1b35153.json was not found in the build context. If it was working before, you most probably deleted that file.

Comment: You want to copy 2 local files to the image right? Not sure this works as you pasted in your example ... try out like explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/30316600/65456

Comment: @Zeitounator I can see this file in my directory. I just moved the the Dockerfiles and this file to a new project directory.

Comment: Then you need to find out why you think the file is there and docker thinks it is not. Hint: human is usually wrong, computer is almost always right.

Comment: @Zeitounator yes that's why I am having a hard time diagnosing it since I can see it in the project directory but for some reason docker thinks its not in the context.

Comment: ... and as pointed out by @ToniVandeVoorde, the correct syntax is `COPY src1 src2... dest` and not `srca desta srcb destb`. For the latest, you need two seperate copy commands.

Comment: @Zeitounator I used the other syntax as well : COPY requirements.txt testproject-264512-9de8b1b35153.json ./ , no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you running docker build command?

In [docker best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/) I've read that docker fails if you try to build your image from `stdin` using `-`

*Attempting to build a Dockerfile that uses COPY or ADD will fail if this syntax is used. The following example illustrates this:*

```
# create a directory to work in
mkdir example
cd example

# create an example file
touch somefile.txt

docker build -t myimage:latest -<<EOF
FROM busybox
COPY somefile.txt .
RUN cat /somefile.txt
EOF

# observe that the build fails
...
Step 2/3 : COPY somefile.txt .
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder249218248/somefile.txt: no such file or directory
```

I've reproduced issue... Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.7

## ENV Variables
ENV PYTHON_VERSION="3.6.5"
ENV BUCKET_NAME='detection-sandbox'
ENV DIRECTORY='/usr/local/gcloud'

# working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY kk.txt ./ \
     kk.2.txt ./
```

If I create image by running `docker build -t testImage:1 [DOCKERFILE_FOLDER]`, docker creates image and works correctly.

However if I try the same command from `stdin` as:

```
docker build -t test:2 - <<EOF
FROM alpine:3.7

ENV PYTHON_VERSION="3.6.5"
ENV BUCKET_NAME='detection-sandbox'
ENV DIRECTORY='/usr/local/gcloud'

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY kk.txt ./      kk.2.txt ./
EOF
```

I get the following error:

```
Step 1/6 : FROM alpine:3.7
 ---> 6d1ef012b567
Step 2/6 : ENV PYTHON_VERSION="3.6.5"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 734d2a106144
Step 3/6 : ENV BUCKET_NAME='detection-sandbox'
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 18fba29fffdc
Step 4/6 : ENV DIRECTORY='/usr/local/gcloud'
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d926a3b4bc85
Step 5/6 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 57a1868f5f27
Step 6/6 : COPY kk.txt ./      kk.2.txt ./
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder518467298/kk.txt: no such file or directory
```

It seems that docker build images from `/var/lib/docker/tmp/` if you build image from stdin, thus `ADD` or `COPY` commands don't work.

Comment: I am using the following command : docker build -t test-docker .

Comment: what's your working directory, could you use complete path in command instead of `.`? e.g `docker build -t  test:1 /home/anino/kk`

Comment: I tried with the full path but still the same error :/

Comment: Could you try in another machine?, I've tested your Dockerfile as it is and it works (if files `testproject-264512-9de8b1b35153.json` and `requirements.txt` exists in the same `Dockerfile` path)... You should have some missconfiguration in your build machine and/or file `testproject-264512-9de8b1b35153.json` doesn't exists in the same Dockerfile path...

Comment: I got it know, in my .dockerignore I had excluded .json files , now its resolved, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect path in source is a common error.

Use

```
COPY ./directory/testproject-264512-9de8b1b35153.json /dir/
```

instead of

```
COPY testproject-264512-9de8b1b35153.json /dir/
```