# How to copy multiple directories into a single directory and preserve directory structure

Tags: docker

I would like to copy multiple directories (with contents) to a single directory in my container while maintaining the original directory structure of my project. For example, the relevant line in my Dockerfile looks like this:

```
COPY bin env project ./projects/
```

The command above only copies files into my projects directory and also removes all of the original directory structure of bin, env, and project.

How can I copy several directories (with contents) such that the original directory structures are preserved? I did find [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30316600/1255817), but as the first commenter points out, directory structure is lost with this method.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create the directory structure since `COPY` will only add files not the directory itself.
one approach will be aading them one by one.

```
RUN mkdir -p projects/{bin,env,project}
COPY bin projects/
COPY env projects/
COPY project projects/
```

or maybe using `ADD` will be a better approach since Add will decompress archives download files and [more](https://medium.com/@Grigorkh/dockerfile-add-vs-copy-d120e72d09dd).
so you will need to archive directories first, then use add like below

```
ADD archive.tgz projects/
```