# How to exclude some subfolder in Dockerfile so it wont being built?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have project structure that look like this:

```
apps
--services1
--- here all the file of service1
--services2
--- here all the file of service2
libs
-- Here will have some files, needed by services1 and services2
packages.json
Dockerfile.service1
Dockerfile.service2
docker-compose.yml
```

in my `Dockerfile.service1` then I do like this:

```
FROM node:12.17-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /build
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn

COPY . .
RUN  yarn build:services1

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "yarn", "start:services1"]
```

`Dockerfile.service2` also having the same command

So right now my problem is:

`Dockerfile.services1` and `Dockerfile.services2` both will `COPY` all the project file into the image, means that `Service1Image` will contain files of `apps/services2` file.

Soon, the project will have 50 services, inside `apps` folder, therefore in order to build 1 docker image for 1 service, the image will contain files of 50 microservices.

**Question:**

Is it anyway to exclude folder in `apps` folder excepts `apps/services1` in `Service1Image`? But it need to include `libs`, `packages.json` inside `Service1Image`, and the same way to `Service2Image`.  Is it possible?

**My attempt**

```
FROM node:12.17-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /build

// I only copy `libs` `apps/services1`, is this right??
COPY package.json yarn.lock libs apps/services1 ./
RUN yarn

COPY . .
RUN  yarn build:app-one

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "yarn", "start:app-one"]
```

Comment: Checkout multi-stage builds https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Comment: why not just copy in the things you do want instead of copying everything and trying to specify what you dont want. it sounds like you only need to copy the libs and services 1 stuff. so just copy those. othewise when you have 50 services instead of just specifying 2 things to copy you will end up specifying 50 things to not copy and this will be bulky and unmanagable over time

Comment: @D.B.K so I should by for `libs` in `stage1`, then in `stage2` by for `apps/services1` like this right??

Comment: @ChrisDoyle YES, that what I want. But I just havent figure it out

Comment: are you using webpack? if yes, i would suggest running `yarn build` in stage1 and then copy over JUST the artifact, i.e the output of webpack build , probably `build` folder to stage2 and include just that in your final docker image

Comment: @D.B.K I'm not using webpack for this project so far, just a Nestjs monorepo which have the structure above. I have an attempt in the question, am I doing it right??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30256386/how-to-copy-multiple-files-in-one-layer-using-a-dockerfile

Comment: @ChrisDoyle tq sir, seen that