# Is there a better way to copy files and folders to a docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

This is what I came up with but it seems clunky to me. Is there a way to streamline the COPY command? Note that not all the folders need to copied.

I did check out [Docker's documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) regarding, and it seems like this may be the only way? I was just checking if anyone else had a brighter idea. Thanks!

```
# Copy files to container
COPY src/ /opt/build_area/src/
COPY public/  /opt/build_area/public/
COPY app.js doc* .en* tag-push.sh react-0.3.1.tgz package.json .npmrc /opt/build_area/
```

This is the folder structure:

```
$ tree -L 1
.
├── .dockerignore
├── .env
├── .env.development
├── .git/
├── .gitignore
├── .npmrc
├── Dockerfile
├── Dockerfile-build
├── README.md
├── app.js
├── azure-pipelines-static.yml
├── azure-pipelines.yml
├── docker/
├── docker-compose-run.yml
├── docker-compose.yml
├── node_modules/
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── public/
├── react-0.3.1.tgz
├── src/
├── tag-push.sh
└── test-azure-pipelines-static.yml

5 directories, 18 files
```

Comment: check this possible duplicate:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30256386/how-to-copy-multiple-files-in-one-layer-using-a-dockerfile

Comment: The other shortcut I'd use here is to set `WORKDIR /opt/build_area`, and then `COPY src/ ./src/`, `COPY files ./` relative to that `WORKDIR` to avoid repeating the directory name.

Comment: @TahaNaqvi, That is a great post which helps.  Thank you!

Comment: @DavidMaze, that is a great idea! Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy multiple files in one layer using a Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30256386/how-to-copy-multiple-files-in-one-layer-using-a-dockerfile)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with helpful comments from @TahaNaqvi and @DavidMaze. This is much easier to read.

```
# Copy files to container
WORKDIR /opt/build_area/

COPY src/ ./src/
COPY public/  ./public/

COPY app.js           \
     .npmrc           \
     doc* .en*        \
     tag-push.sh      \
     package.json     \
     react-0.3.1.tgz  /opt/build_area/
```

Answer (score 1):

dockerignore file can be used just like gitignore file. You can specify files folders to be ignored which will not be copied by COPY command. More doc here - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file

Comment: Mind. Blown. And then I can just do a `COPY * <dest dir>`.  I'll put that in my pocket for later!