# Can't copy specific files to /app in a Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker

I want to copy all of my python ,`.py`, files in my folder to my `/app` folder and according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30256386/how-to-copy-multiple-files-in-one-layer-using-a-dockerfile) SO question I should be able to just do

```
FROM python:3.10.2-slim-bullseye

#Copy stuff into /app
COPY ./*.py /app

# set workdir as "/app"
WORKDIR /app 

#run
python train.py
```

but it throws the error `mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/jonf4h3njxr8zj28bxlyw7ztd/merged/app: not a directory` when it reaches the third line `WORKDIR /app`.

I have tried several "versions" i.e `COPY *.py /app`, `COPY /*.py /app` but neither works

If I just copy everything i.e `COPY . /app` it works fine, but insted of floating my `.dockerignore` with stuff I don't need, I just want to copy my python-files only.

Comment: Did you try setting the workdir before you make the copy. Also from the docker page of python, the work dir is located at /usr/src/app. ```WORKDIR /usr/src/app COPY *.py ./```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the app directory first

```
FROM python:3.10.2-slim-bullseye

# Create directory
RUN mkdir /app

#Copy stuff into /app
COPY ./*.py /app

# set workdir as "/app"
WORKDIR /app 

#run
python train.py
```

Comment: But why does it work when I just copy everything i.e `COPY . /app` ?

Comment: Because then it copies the folder, not files in the folder.

Comment: But if the issue is that "app" doens't exist, then it shouldn't make any difference if I try to copy files or folders to "/app"?

Comment: when you use "COPY ." it copies a folder and renames it to "app" but when you use "COPY ./*.py" it copies files so it cannot find folder named "app"

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary; [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) is documented to create the destination directory if it doesn't exist (as does `WORKDIR`).

Answer (score 2):

The Dockerfile [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) directive has some fussy rules over the syntax of the right-hand side.  The documentation currently states:

> If multiple `<src>` resources are specified, either directly or due to the use of a wildcard, then `<dest>` must be a directory, and it must end with a slash `/`.
>
> If `<dest>` does not end with a trailing slash, it will be considered a regular file and the contents of `<src>` will be written at `<dest>`.

So when you `COPY` a single `*.py` file to `/app` without a trailing slash, the Dockerfile creates a *file* named `/app` that's the single Python file.  Then you get the error from `WORKDIR` that `/app` isn't a directory, it's the Python file.

Make sure the right-hand side of `COPY` ends with a slash:

```bash
COPY *.py /app/ # <-- ends with /
```